# Xpath select n-th node

Tags: xpath

I have a XML like this

```
<div class="yay">
 <div class="foo"></div> 
 <div class="foo"></div>
 <div class="bar"></div>
 <div class="foo"></div>
 <div class="bar"></div>
 <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to select the n-nth div where class is "foo"?

I'd select all foos with `//div[@class="yay"/div[@class="foo"]`

If I want to select foo #3 how do I do that? Something like:

`//div[@class="yay"/div[@class="foo"][3]` ?

Comment: Did you try what you suggested?  If so, what did you get?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This is one of the most FAQ in XPath**.

**Use**:

```
(//div[@class="yay"]/div[@class="foo"])[3]
```

**Explanation**:

The XPath pseudo-operator `//` has lower precedence (priority) that the `[]` operator.

**Thus**

```
//div[@class="yay"]/div[@class="foo"][3]
```

**means**:

*Select every `div` whose `class` attribute has the value `"foo"` and that (the `div`) is the third such `div` child of its parent*.

If there are more than one parent `div` elements that have three or more such children, then *all* of the 3rd children are selected.

**As with many expression languages, the way to override built-in priority is to use parenthesis**.

Comment: Incredible what power brackets can have. Thank you. It worked like a charm 

Comment: @chainstair Yes, the same power as the comma in natural languge: these two sentences have dramatically different meaning: "`Pardon him do not, execute him`"  and "`Pardon him, do not execute him`"  :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me so you are correct, `//div/div[@class="foo"][2]` or did you want to select for example element number 3 under 'yay' and see if its 'foo'?